# How does Task.CurrentId work?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task, windows-store-apps

I am currently learning how to use Tasks, async and await in Windows Store ("Metro") apps. I stumbled upon the property `Task.CurrentId` and try to understand how it works.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.currentid.aspx) it returns *"An integer that was assigned by the system to the currently-executing task"*. So I added logging this value to my custom logger, but to my surprise none of my test apps ever logged anything but `null`.

Look at this example:

```
private async void TestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int? id1 = Task.CurrentId;

    await Task.Delay(100);
    int? id2 = Task.CurrentId;

    StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("test.txt", 
        CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    int? id3 = Task.CurrentId;

    await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "test");
    int? id4 = Task.CurrentId;

    await DoMoreAsync();
    int? id7 = Task.CurrentId;
}

private async Task DoMoreAsync()
{
    StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("test.txt",
        CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    int? id5 = Task.CurrentId;

    await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "test");
    int? id6 = Task.CurrentId;
}
```

All these ids are `null`. Why? This code does create tasks, doesn't it? Shouldn't they have an id?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because you're using `async / await`, all your `Task.CurrentId` calls are happening on the UI thread.

The UI thread is not a `Task`, so it has a null `CurrentId`

---

If you create a `Task`, its `CurrentId` will be set:

```
int? idTask = await Task.Run( () => Task.CurrentId );
```

Comment: Aha. So the call to the implicitly created callback (for the code after await) is dispatched to the UI thread?

Comment: Yes, a custom windows message is posted to the message loop. When it is handled, the "continuation" is executed as a normal method on the UI thread. You can see the call stack if you set a break point after an `await` that yields.

Comment: So continuation is dispatched to UI thread, or to thread from which is initiated async task? Or there are way to configure task how manage continuation?

Comment: What is the difference between 'Task.CurrentId' and 'Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedId' ?

Answer (score 16):

> According to MSDN it returns "An integer that was assigned by the system to the currently-executing task"
>   ...
>   This code does create tasks, doesn't it? Shouldn't they have an id?

The key there is "currently-executing".

There are two types of `Task`s: one type of task executes code, and the other type of task is just an abstract representation of some kind of operation or event. For examples, `Task.Run` will create a code-executing task that will execute its code on a thread pool thread; `Task.Delay` will create an operation/event task that completes when a timer fires.

The tasks returned by `async` methods represent the method itself, so they are actually an operation/event task instead of a code task. The code in `async` methods may run as delegates or as several different tasks (or a mixture of both). Even if you do get a `CurrentId` from within an `async` method (which indicates you're running inside a code-executing task), that id would be different than the id of the task returned by the method (which is always an operation/event task).

Comment: is there an overview of these task/async internals somewhere?  Thanks!

Comment: @MikeJansen: I describe the two types [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html), with another post [specifically dealing with `CurrentId`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/a-tour-of-task-part-4-id.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example, that gives more insights about what's going on:

```
Task task1 = Task.Delay(500);
Task task2 = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    Console.WriteLine($"Task.CurrentId:" + Task.CurrentId);
    await task1;
    Console.WriteLine($"Task.CurrentId:" + Task.CurrentId);
});
Console.WriteLine($"task1.Id:" + task1.Id);
Console.WriteLine($"task2.Id:" + task2.Id);
await task2;
```

Output:

```
task1.Id:1
task2.Id:2
Task.CurrentId:3
Task.CurrentId:
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Btazf7).

The [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) with `async` delegate is a combination of the [`Task.Factory.StartNew`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew) and the [`Unwrap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap). The `Task.Factory.StartNew` returns a nested `Task<Task>`, and the `Unwrap` combines these two tasks, the outer and the inner, to one `Task`. The [`Task.CurrentId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.currentid) has a value while the outer task is running, and becomes `null` when the outer task has completed and the inner task is launched. The inner task is a promise-style task, not a delegate-based task like the outer task. So typically it is not running on a specific thread during its execution. It might use multiple threads, and it might not use [any thread at all](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) for most of its lifetime.

In the above example the `task2` is the unwrapped `Task`, and has the Id 2. The nested `Task<Task>` (the outer task) has the Id 3, as we can see by the `Task.CurrentId` before the `await`. After the `await` the outer task has completed, and the inner task has been launched. The inner task is `async`-generated.

The static `CurrentId` property is implemented [internally](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/release/7.0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L1211) like this:

```
[ThreadStatic]
internal static Task? t_currentTask;  // The currently executing task.

public static int? CurrentId
{
    get
    {
        Task? currentTask = t_currentTask;
        if (currentTask != null)
            return currentTask.Id;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

The `t_currentTask` is a `ThreadStatic` field that gets a value when the execution of a task starts on a thread, and reverts to its previous value when the execution completes. So as you can see this feature is heavily associated with threads. When the promise-style tasks came into play at a later stage of the .NET evolution, the `CurrentId` was left behind. It was probably intended as a debugging feature anyway, for facilitating testing and for `Debug` assertions. It was not intended for controlling the execution flow of production apps. I can see it used in the whole dotnet/runtime repository in only [11 files](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/search?q=Task.CurrentId), always for logging, testing, and debugging.