# Why Task.CurrentId sometimes is null?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task

This is my code. When I comment `Task.Delay` line of code, the `Task.CurrentId` will be equal to 1. When I have `Task.Delay`, `Task.CurrentId` will be equal to `null`. Why?

I am trying to create a `Mutex` class with reentrancy possibility. So I need to understand the concept of the Tasks fully. We expect that number of threads and the thread that might execute a task might be different, but why creation of tasks are different just by using or not using `Task.Delay` method?

```
static void Main()
{
    Class1.Run();
    Console.WriteLine("ran");
    Console.ReadLine();
    return;
}
```

```
internal class Class1
{
    public static async void Run()
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("ID:" + Task.CurrentId);
        Task.Run(AA);            
    }

    static async Task AA()
    {
        //await Task.Delay(1000);
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("ID:" + Task.CurrentId);
        await AA();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Why do you care? 2) The code is buggy and whatever you see is *not* what you assume. `async void` methods can't be awaited which means your code can exit before any task had a chance to even start. An `async` method will at the first `await`. If the method isn't awaited in turn, execution will simply continue.

Comment: When you *don't* use `Task.Delay()`, you're still running on the original thread. There's no task active. `"ID:" + Task.CurrentId` will be evaluated *before* the call to `await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos However, without Task.Delay, the AA's Task.CurrentId does in fact produce an id, but *with* Task.Delay, it doesn't.

Comment: My **guess** is that Task.Run spins up a task, that runs the first part of AA, including the `Task.CurrentID` expression, which thus yields an id. However, if you add `Task.Delay`, the continuation will be marshalled back to the sync context which is the main thread, and this is not a task, so then the id is lost. Mind you, a **big** ***guess***.

Comment: Tasks aren't threads. They're a *promise* that something will produce a value in the *future*. These are the actual terms used in other languages. They represent a piece of work that may or may *not* run on a thread. The task returned by a network operation represents the result that will be returned after a while. The task in `Task.Delay()` hides a Timer behind it, that signals completion when it expires. `Task.Run()` returns a task whose payload will be executed by a threadpool thread

Comment: `I am trying to create a Mutex class with reentrancy possibility.` why do you want that? It's almost certain the original problem is solved already, but that isn't obvious because you treat tasks as threads. Concurrent collections don't need locking. Producer/Consumer classes like Channel<T> don't require locking to push data from a producer to a consumer on another thread. In general, parallel code should *avoid* global state even if it doesn't require locks. That's why DataFlow classes like ActionBlock, TransformBlock, process data items in a pipeline of processing tasks

Comment: Related: [How does Task.CurrentId work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399232/how-does-task-currentid-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to create a Mutex class with reentrancy possibility.

Synchronous monitors (including `lock`) are already re-entrant. Asynchronous locks (like `SemaphreSlim`) are normally *not* re-entrant. It is possible to build one but extremely complex (in particular, you can't just use `Task.CurrentId` as a replacement for `System.Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId`).

IMO [re-entrant locks are an antipattern anyway](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/recursive-re-entrant-locks.html) (link is to my blog where I explain why I think this).

> Why Task.CurrentId sometimes is null?

`CurrentId` is `null` when there is not a currently-executing task.

> We expect that number of threads and the thread that might execute a task might be different, but why creation of tasks are different just by using or not using Task.Delay method?

It seems there's some invalid assumptions taking place. There's a few different ways to clarify.

First, there are two types of tasks: [Promise Tasks and Delegate Tasks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html#:%7E:text=There%20are%20two%20types%20of,kind%20of%20event%20or%20signal.) (link to my blog). Delegate Tasks execute code; their code has a `CurrentId`. Promise Tasks represent some future event; they don't *have* code, so they never have an observable `CurrentId`.

Asynchronous code uses Promise Tasks. When you have an `async` method, the `Task` that is returned is a Promise Task, not a Delegate Task. The task doesn't actually execute the code; it just *represents* the execution of that code. When the code completes, that acts as an event that completes the Promise Task.

The code in an `async` method is usually [scheduled onto a `SynchronizationContext` or the thread pool](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) (as described on my blog). Although, in the rare situation where `SynchronizationContext.Current` is `null` and `TaskScheduler.Current` is not `TaskScheduler.Default`, the code would be scheduled onto a `TaskScheduler` and would actually run as a Delegate Task and have a `CurrentId`. Note that the Delegate Task in this case *only* covers a synchronous chunk of the `async` method, and other parts of the `async` method code would have a different `CurrentId` (or none at all).

`Task.Run` is a bit different. It actually has code to run, and it may schedule it onto an actual Delegate Task. If it's given a synchronous delegate, it may schedule a Delegate Task and return it (this behavior is undocumented and may change). If it's given an asynchronous delegate, it might (or might not) start by scheduling a Delegate Task but it would have to return a Promise Task. If you're familiar with `StartNew`, it's sort of similar: `StartNew` returns Delegate Tasks but `Unwrap` returns Promise Tasks.

So, synchronous code passed to `Task.Run` may have a `Task.CurrentId`, and the first synchronous chunk of asynchronous code passed to `Task.Run` may also have a `Task.CurrentId`. But neither of those behaviors are guaranteed.

And in the more general case, asynchronous code cannot depend on `Task.CurrentId` being valid or useful for anything. It's at a different level of abstraction.

Comment: Also found an [old blog post of mine on `Task.CurrentId` in `async` methods](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/03/taskcurrentid-in-async-methods.html) that I didn't even remember existed... I must be getting old...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was using threads, and I had a thread for each client connected to server. I have a room class which contains some data and methods and is shared between different those threads. e.g. some of the methods have null check at the beginning ensuring those variables are not changed by any other thread until that work is finished. 
Now I am using async functions. Threads are reduced from 700 to 70 (for 600 users) and the performance is slightly better.
As methods may call each other, I need reentrancy support.

Comment: "The task doesn't actually execute the code; it just represents the execution of that code."
I think I need to know the exact definition of a task. I didn't see it on Microsoft website. I hoped I can understand tasks by checking when a new task is created using Task.CurrentId.

Comment: @Dadkhah it might be possible to redesign your existing code, so that the requirement for reentrant locks is eliminated. You could consider presenting your scenario in an another question, including all the important details and minimal code, and asking for ideas.